# My first list item "All" text in the nav bar is not center like the rest

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar in the header of this menu landing page I'm working on and for some reason the first list item in the nav bar ("All") is not center and the rest of the list items are. The list items have borders around them. Is there a way i can get the "all" list item text to center like the rest of the the list items are.

```css
#header #NavBar {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;   
}

#header #NavBar li {
    display: inline;
    
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#header p {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    color:#ffcc00;
    font-weight:100;  
}

#header #NavBar #all {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ffcc00;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#header #NavBar #all {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ffcc00;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#header #NavBar #breakfast {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ffcc00;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#header #NavBar #lunch {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ffcc00;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#header #NavBar #dinner {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ffcc00;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#header img  {
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: -65px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Brunch Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
<header id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1035649/7783/v/600/depositphotos_77833254-stock-illustration-restaurant-logo.jpg">
    <p>Menu</p>
    <ul id="NavBar">
        <li id="all"><a href="#">All<a /></li>
        <li id="breakfast"><a href="#">Breakfast<a/></li>
        <li id="lunch"><a href="#">Lunch<a/></li>
        <li id="dinner"><a href="#">Dinner<a/></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: Close the `<a>` tag correctly. Currently, its `<a />`. It should be `</a>`

Comment: Please also note that you can have a single `#header #NavBar a` css rule to cover all your links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes.

First, your anchor tag must be like `<a href="#"></a>` not `<a/>`

Then your css must be like this. Check this 3 tags make changes I made. Add `#logo` and `header` tags. Delete everything in `#header img` and use flex as I used.

```css
#header img  {
  /* Use img like this */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#logo {
  max-width: 100px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* Remove this after you understand flex */
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

Finally change your markup like this

```html
<header id="header">
  <img id="logo" src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1035649/7783/v/600/depositphotos_77833254-stock-illustration-restaurant-logo.jpg">
  <p>Menu</p>
  <ul id="NavBar">
    <li id="all"><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li id="breakfast"><a href="#">Breakfast</a></li>
    <li id="lunch"><a href="#">Lunch</a></li>
    <li id="dinner"><a href="#">Dinner</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you to read here carefully. You will understand how centering and aligning works. `https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/`